# How do a change an image inside an anchor when you are on the said page of the anchor

Tags: css, wordpress, image, src

How do i change an image, which is (inside an anchor) for another image (exactly the same width and height), once it (the anchor) has been clicked? - using CSS

so...

```
<a href="http://etc.co.uk/"><img src="etc.png"></a>
```

I want my etc.png to show as a different image once you have clicked the anchor. any ideas? Would LOVE if someone could help me with this

Comment: as fa as i know CSS by itself cant do that, but with JavaScript or jquery is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I assume you're talking about an anchor link or a target blank link - otherwise I don't see the point of changing the image if the user leave the page.

There is no perfect CSS-only solution for that situation. You could play with the pseudo classes of your link and set your image as background of `a`.

HTML :

```
<a href="http://etc.co.uk/" class="etc-link" target="_blank"></a>
```

CSS :

```
a.etc-link {
    background: url("blah.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

**With :active**

```
a.etc-link:active {
    background-image: url("blah-active.jpg");
}
```

Pro : accept the background-image property

Cons : lost after the link is opened

**With :visited**

You can use `:visited` only with few css properties: background-color, color and border / outline color. You could eventually play with `background-color` and a png file with transparency.

One thing to note is that `:visited` is persistent as long it is in the user browser history.

**With Javascript**

The better of course if you can is to use Javascript. You don't need jQuery for that, this simple line will do the trick:

```
<a href="http://etc.co.uk/" target="_blank" onclick="this.firstElementChild.src='etc-active.jpg'"><img src="etc.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<a href="http://etc.co.uk/"><img src="etc.png" onclick=src="blah.jpg"></a>
```